# Can you lose the privilege to ask a question?

Tags: support, post-ban

I've seen comments posted that a particular individual is in jeopardy of losing their question asking privileges. (Because of a history of down voted questions) If a rep point of "1" is required to ask a question, how could they not be able to ask a question? Does this ultimately mean they are being banned from the site? Is this documented somewhere, I can't seem to find it.

Comment: It's called post-ban and it's not bond to rep: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: @tohecz This is helpful.  Thanks